# Class not found after auto loading in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, autoload

I am struggling with `PHP Namespaces` and `Auto loading` in `Laravel 5.4`. I actually decided to put the models that I need to use in a definite and named folder as `app/Models`:

`php artisan make:model Models/Customer`

I have set Customer model's namespace to `namespace Models;`
Then, I created a route as follows:

```
Route::get('customer', function () {
    $customer = \App\Models\Cutomer::find(1);
    echo $customer;
});
```

To do auto loading work I opened the `composer.json` file located in the very root folder of the `Laravel` project and made the `autoload` to be as follows:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database",
        "app/Models"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "App\\Models\\": "App/Models"
    }
},
```

After all of this I checked if my composer is an update version and ran `dump-autoload`:

```
composer self-update
composer dump-autoload -o
```

There is also worth of notice the contents of `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`:

```
'App\\Models\\Customer' => $baseDir . '/app/Models/Customer.php',
'App\\Models\\Test\\Test' => $baseDir . '/app/Models/Test.php',
```

My problem is that whenever I execute the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/customer` I will encounter the following error output:

```
(1/1) FatalThrowableError
Class 'App\Models\Cutomer' not found
```

Would you please help me understand where of my work has been incorrect, and how to fix it? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You have a typo. The model is `Customer`, but you're trying to use `Cutomer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace in the model should be `namespace App\Model;` (hence why you call the class as `\App\Models\Cutomer`)

When you use `php artisan make:model Models/Customer` it should have set the namespace correctly then.

Also, you don't need to edit your `composer.json` to do this. Remove the additions you've made to your `composer.json` file for the autoloading and then run `composer dumpautoload` from the command line.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you all three of you helping me solve my problem. I should not only have paid attention to `namespacing` but I also had a typo. You all saved my day. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 1):

First, you have an error in your PSR-4 setup.

`"App\\Models\\": "App/Models"`

This does not map to a valid directory. Secondly, and more importantly, there is no need to autoload a nested namespace of one that is already declared. By autoloading `App` you will already autoload any nested namespaces as long as they conform to PSR-4 standards i.e namespace as directory name and filename as class name.

Composer setup only needs to be the following:

```
"psr-4": {
    "App\\": "app/"
}
```